# Disable Billing and shipping address in Magento Checkout

Tags: php, magento, billing

Now I'm in a situation that, I need to skip the billing address in my magento site.

I tried out installing a module [Express checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/express-checkout-2845.html). But it wont help since it will do it for all products and will replace the `checkout.xml`.

I need to do it for some certain products only(Which does't have home delivery option. Only be picked up from store).

How can it be done? Please share if you know basic idea of disabling billing and shipping address in default magento checkout page.

Comment: Not very easy to explain, but in short what I did: in onepage I removed the billing step and in the onepage controller I made sure the shipping address was used as billing address (after all you do need both). It's possible you have to modify optcheckout.js as well.

Comment: did you get a solution? if you got solution please share with me.